# Wrapper Class for PDOStatement Class

Tags: php, pdo, wrapper

after a long research on the pros and cons of wrapping/extending the PDO class and the PDOStatement class, I came to the conclusion that I want to wrap both classes rather than extending them.

Now I face the following problem: I got also wrapper methods for the fetch- and fetchAll-method, which leads to a memory overload:

```
public function fetch_row($style = null, $orientation_cursor = null, $offset_cursor = null)
{
    return $this->driver->fetch($style, $orientation_cursor, $offset_cursor);
}
```

I did not know that PHP probably reserves extra memory for the returned arrays that are just passed by with return.

Is there a way to tell PHP to not use memory for that? Do you have another possible architecture to solve my issue under the circumstance that I want to keep the wrapper classes?

Thank you already in advance for your help,

Freddy

Comment: Would be nice to hear why you vote the thread down -1 ...

Comment: There is really not enough solid information in this question. No actual error message, no code of any use for someone to attempt to duplicate your situation. All you are going to get from this is people having a guess or the ubiquitous, oh I had something like that  and changed this, which is basically just another guess.

Comment: The thing I wanted to get out of this question was whether there is extra memory usage if I pass the returned variable again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an exemplary offtopic question, as it's asks to explain a [groundless] assumption, yet fails to provide some reproduceable case as a proof.

So, just from my experience I can tell that

1. No, PHP never reserve any memory in advance, just in case.
2. Most likely your problem is caused by the [buffered query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) that returned too much data, which is irrelevant to your wrappers.
3. PDO is a good wrapper itself, with extremely very few things to improve. And one have to think twice before reinventing the wheel.